# How to set width and height, and add a border to Expo BarCodeScanner inside a view

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to have an Expo BarCodeScanner inside of a view on a screen.

I've been using vw and vh for width and height because I want it to change based on the amount of screen space I have. I've tried putting a border around it but it never shows up. I've tried putting it on the view around the barcodescanner as well as the scanner itself.

Here is the code snippet of my barcodescanner as well as the corresponding styles and screenshot.

```
scannerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: vw(100),
    maxHeight: vh(50),
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderColor: colors.primary,
    borderWidth: 5
}

<View style={styles.scannerContainer}>
    <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={(hasScan) ? undefined : handleScan}
        barCodeTypes={[BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.qr]}
        style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject]}
    />
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share on snack ?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@laneherby/a73d84

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the barcode you can use `expo camera` because `BarCodeScanner` have active issue.

Here is the code

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

<Camera
  onBarCodeScanned={this.onBarCodeScanned}
  ratio='16:9'
  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
/>
```

Link: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5212